# How do laws affect photography of non-humans in public when people may be in the frame?

Tags: australia, privacy, right-of-publicity, photography

Given that this is taking place in a public area where one would not have an expectation of privacy, what legal restrictions exist on photography of people where they are **not** the subject of the photograph?

For instance, say that I am taking a photograph of a popular statue, and people happen to be in the frame? Assume this is in Australia; New south Wales, specifically, but I am interested in answers for other states also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's put to bed the myth of privacy that is at the heart of your question: in [R v Sotheren (2001) NSWSC 204](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/cases/nsw/supreme_ct/2001/204.html) Justice Dowd said **“A person, in our society, does not have a right not to be photographed.”**

In general, you **can** take photos of people; statues have even *less* privacy rights.

There are limitations mainly related to voyeurism and commercial use, which are discussed at http://www.4020.net.

Comment: "Statues have even less privacy rights." Heh.

Comment: The language pedant in me wants it to say _fewer_ rights. The linguist in me doesn't care.