# Street Photography with a subject of a person in mind

Tags: privacy, photography

### Context

So I take pictures on the street and from searching on the Law SE, it seems that people should not expect any privacy rights, when out in public. My question is a variant of some of the others listed below under related where images are used in a non COMMERCIAL blog.

### Question

My question is that if I'm taking picture of a person in particular, at a costume event for example, can I post it online to show off my photography skills and also write about it in a blog? I presume the answer is yes as it would follow under an editorial usage? (I'm not trying to defame or slander people or use the images in a negative light.)

Related if they say no but I've already taken a picture of them, is there any legal action they can take against me, if I do post it, or even have the image but never use it? (I wouldn't do this out of politeness but I'm curious. I'm also not trying to harass them for a picture after if they say no.) In a more general sense, do people who either know they are being photographed and pose for the camera or are indifferent to the camera have the same legal actions after their picture is taken, that is to saw a person may like their picture but later on realize they don't want to be in an article?

In the above cases, all images posted are NOT for commercial use and again are used for blogging or related purposes only.

### Related

- [Do people generally have the right not to be photographed on private property?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/660)
- [How do laws affect photography of non-humans in public when people may be in the frame?(AU)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/659)
- [Is it legal to post a photograph that I captured of a stranger in the street?(AU)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3540)
- [Model release for image without faces(AU)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4617)
- [What are the legal repercussions of taking a stranger's picture in public?(US)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/247)
- [What is considered “public” in the context of taking videos or audio recordings?(CA)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1369)

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., you can legally photograph anything you want that is visible from the public. This includes photo/video taken on private property when you're not trespassing, and on city/county/state/federal property.
If you take photos of someone and it's not for commercial use, you can do anything you want with them.

Answer (score -1):

> ... can I post it online to show off my photography skills and also write about it in a blog?

Yes, its your photograph, do what you like with it.

> ...  is there any legal action they can take against me, if I do post it, or even have the image but never use it?

Yes, they can take legal action against you ... they won't win though.

These questions give essentially this answer:

- [Is it legal to post a photograph that I captured of a stranger in the street?(AU)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3540)
- [Model release for image without faces(AU)](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4617)