# Legality of street webcams?

Tags: copyright, privacy, human-rights

Let's say your house window is right in front of a famous monument, and you want to enable people to see it at any time of the day and night with a webcam.

Obviously when you place the webcam towards the monument, a lot of things from the street will be broadcasted over which you have no control (people's faces, car plates, street advertisement, shop fronts, etc).

Can you be liable for something for displaying life outside your window? In what circumstances (like, if you make profit from it maybe)?

EDIT: Jurisdictions for which I am interested in  knowing the answer: USA, France.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the legal repercussions of taking a stranger's picture in public?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/247/what-are-the-legal-repercussions-of-taking-a-strangers-picture-in-public)

Comment: A stranger's face is only part of my question. In my question, objects and trademarks or even artworks, not only people, would appear in front of the camera without any relation to the person who placed the webcam. The person who placed the webcam did NOT aim it at someone in particular unlike in the other question.

Comment: @fabriced then they are multiple questions.

Comment: No, they are not several questions because the person placing the camera is unaware of what might show up in front of it (so the possible questions are hard to list!). But taking a stranger's picture is a wilful act, since it implies a person points a camera to someone's face (creepy camera guy in Dale's link), whereas my question is about what happens with a camera aiming at a public space. If you are unaware of the street webcam phenomenon, please go check some links on this topic until you better understand it, thanks :D Here's a link: http://www.earthcam.com