# Video Recording Cops

Tags: traffic, police, us-constitution, consent

I was wondering of the USA legalities of maintaining recorded video with audio when it comes to cops pulling you over while driving for whatever reason?

I wasn't sure if you have to verbally tell them they are being recorded, have a big sticker that's visible to them telling them this, or if they even need to give some sort of consent or be told about this up front?

If I wish to post this on YouTube.com or online later do I need their consent to do so without obfuscating their faces? If they tell me to stop recording and to turn it off, is this a violation of constitutional rights and do I have to do this legally?

I certainly don't want to get into any trouble for video and audio recording police traffic stops in an illegal manner, but I know they can body or dash cam record the public without our consent so wondering if there's a double-standard here or if I have a right to do this and whether or not I need to tell them verbally or have a big sticker, etc.

I'll split this question up into more separate questions if needed but I wanted to give some context with other questions, etc. so hopefully this will be helpful to people that may have answers to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, police have no special protection from being recorded; if it is legal to video or audio record a person in that jurisdiction then it is legal to record a police officer in that jurisdiction. Anything that it is legal to do with the recording of a person is legal even if that person is a police officer.

As to if it is legal to record a person see:

- [Is it legal to post a photograph that I captured of a stranger in the street?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/is-it-legal-to-post-a-photograph-that-i-captured-of-a-stranger-in-the-street/3620#3620)
- [Model release for image without faces](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/model-release-for-image-without-faces/4619#4619)
- [How do laws affect photography of non-humans in public when people may be in the frame?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/659/how-do-laws-affect-photography-of-non-humans-in-public-when-people-may-be-in-the/725#725)
- [What are the legal repercussions of taking a stranger's picture in public?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/247/what-are-the-legal-repercussions-of-taking-a-strangers-picture-in-public/989#989)
- [What is considered "public" in the context of taking videos or audio recordings?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/what-is-considered-public-in-the-context-of-taking-videos-or-audio-recordings/1380#1380)