# Is it legal to upload a photo from a private place without the subject's permission?

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, social-media

Last night we had a small gathering in my neighbour's front garden. Her next door neighbour took some pictures and posted them to Facebook. This is not the first time and in the past we have told her that we do not want our pictures taken or posted. In the past she has taken them down, but she just keeps repeating this pattern. Can I get them taken down or do anything against her account? Preferably anonymously.

Comment: [That post](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/49468/is-it-legal-to-upload-a-photo-from-a-public-place-without-the-subjects-permissi) does not directly relate to mine as I was on private property

Comment: You technically don't have a right to privacy standing in your front yard, even if it's private property. If she held a camera over a privacy fence that would be different, but if you can be seen by anybody on the street, you typically don't have that right.

Comment: @Adam as Ron says, in the UK if you can be seen from a public place then there is no general or automatic right or expectation of privacy.

Comment: I edited the subject to make clear the difference between this and the proposed duplicate and have voted to re-open.