Photographs taken in common areas
I took a photograph of a person letting his dog excrete in the common area of the society which is against the pet policy law in the society and sent it to the maintenance group to impose fine. Is that illegal?

Depends on where that happens and what the legal status of that society is.

At the very least this is going to be country specific, and you haven't told us in what country this occurred.

It's not asking for advice, the question is "is that illegal?" It is a question about the law, which requires jurisdiction to answer properly.  Yes, answers from other jurisdictions are not prohibited by site rules because they lend perspective, but this isn't a general question of that nature.  Because of it's specificity, generic expectation of privacy type answers from jurisdictions other than this "society" are not implicitly invited by the OP.  But, don't let that discourage you or anyone else...

What do you mean by "society" here? To me, a society is an organization of people, not a place.

@Barmar Based off of the OPs name, the words they used, and the grammar that was involved, my impression is that they are not a native English speaker.  So they may be trying to refer to the local equivalent of an HOA in the US.

Probable duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/247/what-are-the-legal-repercussions-of-taking-a-strangers-picture-in-public

It is also going to depend on what you mean by common area.

The answer may very well depend on jurisdiction. I will answer about the law in Canada, itself which varies depending on province.
canada
The Criminal Code has no prohibitions that appear relevant to the scenario you have described.
Common law "intrusion upon seclusion" tort
There is no common law tort of general "breach of privacy" or "invasion of privacy." The tort that comes closest to relating to the hypothetical in your question is known as "intrusion upon seclusion."
This was described in Jones v. Tsige, 2012 ONCA 32, paragraphs 65 and onward. A key element to that tort is that the defendent must have "invaded, without lawful justification, the plaintiff's private affairs or concerns." Also, the tort is only made out if "a reasonable person would regard the invasion as highly offensive." This tort is about "deliberate and significant invasions of personal privacy." And "it is only intrusions into matters such as one's financial or health records, sexual practises and orientation, employment, diary or private correspondence that, viewed objectively on the reasonable person standard, can be described as highly offensive."
Statutory "invasion of privacy" tort
Four provinces do have a stautory tort of invasion of privacy (British Columbia, Manitoba, Saskatchewan, and Newfoundland and Labrador). These all create a cause of action where a person "wilfully and without a claim of right... violate[s] the privacy of another." The degree of privacy to which a person is entitled is that which is reasonable in the circumstances. A person's reasonable expectation of privacy in a public space will be substantially less than in a private space. Some courts have even gone so far as to say "there is no reasonable expectation of privacy for actions taking place in public" (Milner v. Manufacturers Life Insurance Company, 2005 BCSC 1661, para. 77). And: "Even if actions take place on private property, the circumstances may suggest that there is not a reasonable expectation of privacy. ... Although the plaintiff was on private property, it was in full view of any passersby and therefore there was no reasonable expectation of privacy" (para. 78).
